# How to return distances below 10km way flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Managed to sort my snapshots by those nearest to the user's location, but am having trouble showing only those that are within a returned distance of 10(km). I tried writing if statements above return totalDistance in the distance function, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
        c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) *
            (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }


  double distance(Position position, DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    final double myPositionLat = position.latitude;
    final double myPositionLong = position.longitude;
    final double lat = snapshot.data['latitude'];
    final double long = snapshot.data['longitude'];

    double totalDistance = calculateDistance(myPositionLat, myPositionLong, lat, long);
    return totalDistance;
  }





  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((data) async {
      final location = await getLocation();
      print('user location = $location');

      final documents = data.documents;

      documents.sort((a, b) {

        final distanceA = distance(location, a);
        final distanceB = distance(location, b);

        return distanceA.compareTo(distanceB);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) to filter the list. I've never used Dart but I imagine it looks something like this:

```
final documents = data.documents.where((a) => distance(location, a) < 10);
```

Maybe tack on `.toList();` if you want an actual List and not an Iterable.

Comment: You were right! I had to add .toList() for it to work